# Symfony validation constraints annotations not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I am trying to use annotations for Symfony form validation but I can't get it to work. No matter the constraint, the form always reports as valid. I am running on PHP 7.3 with doctrine/annotations 1.13, symfony/validator 5.1 and Symfony 5.1.5.

Here is the basic setup:

**ProductionDependentCost.php**

```
...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
...
    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\NotNull
     * @Assert\Positive
     */
    private $costPerKW = 0;
...
```

**ProductionDependentCostController.php**

```
...
/**
     * @Route("/plant/{id}/productiondependentcosts", name="update_plant_production_dependent_costs", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function updatePlantProductionDependentCosts(Plant $plant, Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('view', $plant);
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductionDependentCostCollectionType::class, $plant, ['csrf_token_id' => 'vue-token']);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $this->em->flush();

            return $this->json('saved!');
        } elseif ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            return $this->json(ErrorUtil::parseErrors($form->getErrors(true)), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return $this->json('this should not be reached!', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
...
```

**config/packages/framework.yaml**

```
framework:
    ...
    validation:
      {
          enable_annotations: true
      }
```

I have many more annotation constraints but included only one in this example to not bloat the code snippet. No matter what I enter in the form (e.g -1000 for costPerKW), it will always return with 'saved!'. I have looked everywhere, but can't seem to find a solution. Really hope that someone knows the answer to this problem.

The form uses a CollectionType on a mapped collection field of **Plant.php**. The collection entries are entities of **ProductionDependentCost.php** and the corresponding FormType uses a simple mapped field for **costPerKW**.

Comment: Are you using javascript to post the data by any chance?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber yes, but it does the same in phpunit tests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Symfony Forms do not automatically validate entities inside collections. As my **ProductionDependentCost** is part of a collection inside my form, I have to add a "Valid" constraint to my collection field:

### Option 1:

```
class Plant
{
...
     /**
     * @var ProductionDependentCost[]|Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=ProductionDependentCost::class, mappedBy="plant", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist",
     * "remove"})
     * @Assert\Valid
     */
    private $productionDependentCosts;
...
}
```

### Option 2:

```
class ProductionDependentCostCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('productionDependentCosts', CollectionType::class,
            [
                ...
                'constraints' => [
                    new Valid(),
                ],
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Plant::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This will validate every collection entity individually.